# VirtualBox seamless mode - all or nothing?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, xfce, xfce4

Because I find Windows suffocatingly inconvenient, I installed a small FreeBSD VM inside VirtualBox, and am doing most of my work there. The GUI running inside the VM is xfce4, and the VBox seamless mode (entered into with RightCtrl-L) works well.

Except for one thing -- bringing *one* X11-client to the foreground, brings *all* X11-clients to the foreground, obscuring the native Windows apps, which is both unexpected and undesired.

For example, if I have:

1. An `xterm` running in the upper left corner,
2. Another `xterm` in the lower right corner,
3. Microsoft Outlook in the center,

clicking on the first `xterm`'s titlebar will bring *both* X11-programs to the foreground, obscuring not only the upper-left portion of Outlook, but also the bottom-right segment...

I *guess*, that's because -- to Windows -- the VM is *one* application, and it brings all of it to the foreground...

Is there a way to change this somehow?

Comment: +1 Windows ***is*** suffocatingly inconvenient ;) I think you have discovered one more inconvenience, but I'd love to hear if there's a workaround.

Comment: Windows is suffocatingly inconvenient, but you absolutely must have all those native  Windows apps running?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, the employer, who provided me with the desktop, insists I use the Outlook and a few other things, which are Windows-only. But the GUI-apps are same (or similar) on any platform. It is the command-line -- or, rather, lack thereof -- that is suffocating on Windows...

Comment: Perhaps you could use Putty and SSH into the VM, and then use Putty terminals instead of xterm? Less than ideal, I know, but maybe this can suit your workflow better?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparantely, this affects even Windows-guests. [Filed a ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19741), maybe, Virtual Box developers will manage to solve this.